# Cómo solucionar el error que aparece al eliminar multiples posts seleccionándolos desde Bulk Actions? - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, eliminar

Tengo un Custom Post Type en el que cada vez que se crea un post, automáticamente se crearán 3 subposts.

Al eliminar el post padre, también se eliminarán los posts hijos. Esto funciona bien si se elimina el post padre desde el botón **'Trash'**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema que tengo es que cuando se eliminan seleccionando desde los checkbox:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muestra el siguiente mensaje:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si actualizo la página, veo que sí se mueven a 'Trash' pero no quiero que aparezca ese mensaje anterior.
Me he dado cuenta que pasa por el código personalizado que tengo para realizar esas acciones de eliminar los posts hijos cuando se da elimina al post padre.
Hay alguna forma para que mi código se ejecute sólo cuando se da en el botón 'Trash' y no cuando se da en eliminar desde los checkbox? O de qué otra manera puedo solucionarlo?

Este es mi código para mover los posts a 'Trash' si se elimina el post padre:

```
// Move to Trash
function trash_post_children($post_id) {
$parent_ID = $post_id;

$args =  array(
    'post_type' => 'companies',
    'post_parent' => $parent_ID,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status' => array('publish', 'pending', 'draft', 'auto-draft', 'future', 'private', 'inherit', 'trash')
);
$children = get_posts($args);
if($children) {
    foreach($children as $p){
        wp_trash_post($p->ID, true);
    }
  }
}
add_action('trashed_post', 'trash_post_children');
```

Answer (score 1):

prueba a meterle la condicional antes de hacer nada. No se muy bien si va a funcionar este codigo pero la idea espero que sirva.

```
       if ( get_post_status( $post_id ) ) {
         $parent_ID = $post_id;

         $args =  array(
         'post_type' => 'companies',
         'post_parent' => $parent_ID,
         'posts_per_page' => -1,
         'post_status' => array('publish', 'pending', 'draft', 'auto- 
          draft', 'future', 'private', 'inherit', 'trash')
          );
         $children = get_posts($args);
         if($children) {
         foreach($children as $p){
           wp_trash_post($p->ID, true);
         }
        }
      }
```

De esta manera solo intentará borrar lo que exista.
Porque al seleccionar varios posts lo que hace es borrar el padre+loshijos, y cuando después intenta borrar un hijo que ya no existe, pues salta el error.